# Is there any zip decompression for iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I found the zlib and gzip decompression algorithms, but I need to compress a whole directory and download it from the server. Would rather not go file at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: nice idea. I see Rob has used MiniZip which looks cool.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. Looks like minizip is the only viable solution at this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ziparchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/), a Google Code project by "acsolu," provides an iPhone-compatible Objective-C wrapper around minizip. With a little adaptation, I found it useful for doing unzip on the iPhone as you described.

Answer (score 5):

I've had good luck using [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I attened a Tacow meeting in Toronto where Karl Kolpanic did a presentation on his ZipKit framework, which he said is also compatible with iPhone development.

It's available over at BitBucket.org: http://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/

Comment: According to the website, it says it requires garbage collection, so in its current form, it's not compatible with iPhone, unfortunately.