# how can we unzip a file in objective c?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any zip decompression for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230351/is-there-any-zip-decompression-for-iphone)

i have a zip file in my document directory and i want to unzip that file using objective c code in xcode how can we do that ? is that possible to do that

thanks 
balraj

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230984/compression-api-on-the-iphone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230351/is-there-any-zip-decompression-for-iphone

Answer (score 4):

i found one greate answer in stack overflow below from this link [download and unzip file in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333399/download-and-unzip-file-in-ios) please check below

I've used [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) with success in the past. It's pretty ligthweight and simple to use, supports password protection, multiple files inside a ZIP, as well as compress & decompress.

The basic usage is:

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ZipFileName" ofType:@"zip"];
ZipArchive *zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
[zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:filepath Password:@"xxxxxx"];
[zipArchive UnzipFileTo:{pathToDirectory} overWrite:YES];
[zipArchive UnzipCloseFile];
[zipArchive release];
```

more examples about this package [here](http://transoceanic.blogspot.in/2011/07/compressuncompress-files-on.html)

I have also tried **[SSZipArchive](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive/blob/master/SSZipArchive.h)** in some projects.
Below line would unzip your zip file.

```
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:path toDestination:destination];
```

Comment: It doesn't work for mac application.