# How can I unzip a file in MacOS X Obj-C?

Tags: cocoa, macos, zip, unzip

How can I unzip a file in MacOS X Obj-C? What frameworks do I need and what is the call?

Comment: Similar SO question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546541/how-can-we-unzip-a-file-in-objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546541/how-can-we-unzip-a-file-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find something helpful [here at CocoaDev](http://cocoadev.com/UsingZipFilesExamples) or with [theunarchiver](http://code.google.com/p/theunarchiver/).  theunarchiver is a nice utility that handles many archive formats and since it's open-source, you may be able to use some of their code to do what you want, though it's LGPL, which may or may not be compatible with what you're doing.

Comment: Your first link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

libz.1.2.3.dylib is the framework you should add to your project.

And use the the classes:
http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/list