# Unzipping downloaded files in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, zip, unzip

Using ASIHTTPRequest, I downloaded a zip file containing a folder with several audio files. I tried to unzip the file with `SSZipArchive` and `ZipArchive`, which are both based on `minizip`.

When I compile the code, I get this error: `Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZipArchive", referenced from: objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o`.

How do I unzip this file in iOS?

Comment: your error means you're using an iPhone-only static library with the simulator...

Comment: @H2CO3: how can I resolve it...

Comment: You can't use this on thesimulator, only on a real device.

Comment: Nice [Zip/Unzip post](http://transoceanic.blogspot.in/2011/07/compressuncompress-files-on.html) with ZipArchive library

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I've used **[ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/)** with success in the past. It's pretty ligthweight and simple to use, supports password protection, multiple files inside a ZIP, as well as compress & decompress.

The basic usage is:

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ZipFileName" ofType:@"zip"];
ZipArchive *zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
[zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:filepath Password:@"xxxxxx"];
[zipArchive UnzipFileTo:{pathToDirectory} overWrite:YES];
[zipArchive UnzipCloseFile];
[zipArchive release];
```

more examples about this package [here](http://transoceanic.blogspot.in/2011/07/compressuncompress-files-on.html)

I have also tried **[SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive)** in some projects.
Below line would unzip your zip file.

```
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:path toDestination:destination];
```

Comment: The latter SSZipArchive one-liner is much easier imo as it also handles writing extracted files. Pretty neat.

Comment: This was the simplest and most lightweight solution that I have evaluated from about 3 top recommendations. ZipArchive works well

Comment: Could you please post how to check empty zip file.

Comment: I have question, how to check unzip successful or unsuccessful ? Is this return any value ?

Comment: @NovusMobile this is such an old answer that I frankly don't remember. I suggest you try it?

Answer (score 2):

To start, in iOS 7, Apple introduced the ability to natively zip / unzip files. You also have the option so send the zip files through Mail, Messages, Airdrop and "Open in". The key is: **The zip file has to be supported by iOS** Some are, and some are not. The first step: Find out if your file is supported. Do this by a simple check of your newly saved file. Try to open it. If it is stuck of "Waiting..." it is *probably* not supported. Try a different library or use a workaround if this is the case.

Now, doing this programmatically **Currently requires** the use of a third party library to save zip files and extract them. This is not ideal, since a lot of people / companies avoid using them. That being said, the answer marked correct, ZipArchive is a great third party tool, especially since it now supports Swift. I would recommend using it until Apple introduces a native library.

Answer (score -5):

On iOS6 a ZIP file seems to be handled like a folder. I had success by simply doing the following:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[NSURL URLForCachesDirectoryWithAppendedPath:@"ZIP_FILE.zip/Contents/Test.m4a"].path
                                        toPath:[NSURL URLForCachesDirectoryWithAppendedPath:@"Test.m4a"].path
                                         error:nil];
```

There might be a chance you can even make a directory listing to unzip files with unknown content. Don't know about password protected ZIP files though.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either: NSUnderlyingError=0x8594310 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Not a directory". Including the correct zip library doesn't seem to help.