# How to display HTML resources downloaded as zipped file in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a requirement where in i have to download a zipped files(basically contains web resource say HTML/JS/CSS files) from internet to iOS device using the iOS application and then display the content of the zipped file using the application. The starting point of the application will be index.html file.

Comment: So, what is your specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to download the zip file from the server using library like [ASIHTTP](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree) 
Then you have to unzip the zipped file using [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive) to a specific folder in your Document folder 
Now just load a UIWebView with the NSURL made from the path of the index.html file inside the unzipped folder.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333399/download-and-unzip-file-in-ios) for decompressing the zip file (it uses an external library for decompression). Use [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to display the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ZipArchive](https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) to Unzip your files at some path

```
- (void)unzipFileAt:(NSString *)sourcePath toPath:(NSString *)destnPath{
    ZipArchive *zipper = [[ZipArchive alloc]init];
    if ([zipper UnzipOpenFile:sourcePath]) {
        [zipper UnzipFileTo:destnPath overWrite:YES];
        [zipper UnzipCloseFile];

    }
}
```

Construct your path for index.html file like this,

```
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/index.html",yourPathWhereTheFileWasUnzipped,pathComponent];
```

Load your UIWebView with the path variable.

```
self.html5View.scalesPageToFit = NO;
[self.html5View  loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
```

This works like a charm for me, for loading HTML5 files.