# Is there a native Cocoa library to parse eBook metadata information?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to get metadata info from a eBook such as author, publication date, publisher, plot, etc. The formats are '.mobi', '.azw', '.azw2', '.azw3', '.epub'.

Is there any cocoa class for that? If not, which libraries do you suggest me?

Comment: 'eBook' is a broad term that doesn't specify what kind of document you need to inspect. If you mean PDF, the Quartz functions for `CGPDFDocument` give you access to the metadata.

Comment: @FruityGeek I need for '.mobi', '.azw', '.azw2', '.azw3', '.epub'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think no, but all those formats have xml based metadata formats, so use any xml parser you like.

Just unzip file and see what inside. For example internals of some `.epub`

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks this is useful. And how do I extract the xml file to parse?

Comment: Sorry one more thing: I'm trying to iterate through the content of the .epub file using  NSBundle * eBookBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path]; but it just doesn't work. I guess because it is not a bundle. How do I access to the files inside?

Comment: you should use zip unarchiver first, search code on github, then NSFileManager  to get files

Comment: So I should use a 3rd party library to unzip it? There is no way to do with native code?

Comment: probably yes, you need additional lib, for example see this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/11333399/1403732

Comment: Ok. So the epub format is actually a zipped file to unzip?

Comment: yes, exactly, is what i want to say from begining)

Comment: I'm back to ask you how to deal with MOBI files? They are not unzippable apparently. How can I extract the xml content? thanks

Comment: sorry, I can't help with this format, try create another question