# iOS native class or library for Unzip file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, unzip

I know there are [many third party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333399/download-and-unzip-file-in-ios) available for unzipping a file.

But are there any native Classes or Libraries available for unzipping a file?

I tried to search but did not find anything!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no native library available for that, there are plenty of third party libraries available though.

However if you think of it, third party libraries are built on top of code so there is a native way to achieve that.

If you are really keen about seeing how to achieve that natively you can dive into the third part code and extract the method you want for the unzipping. However I advice you not to re invent the wheel and use it

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, so many answer I saw, all said there is no native class/library but might be it will be came with iOS 10 or latter one.

Comment: Glad that I helped! if you this this is a good answer please mark it as an answer for this question. Thanks!