# How to use libz.dylib to unzip zip file?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, zlib, libz

in my program i have to unzip downloaded file ... i read libz.dylib is used for that but i didn't find any documentation or examples how to do that..?

any one know this...

Thanks in advance....

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230351/is-there-any-zip-decompression-for-iphone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230984/compression-api-on-the-iphone

Comment: NSString *saveLocation = @"/Volumes/Extra/samples/unzipTest/song.zip";

NSData *zipData=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:saveLocation];
bool b= [[zipData zlibDeflate] writeToFile:@"/Users/admin/Desktop/untitled folder" atomically:YES];

i am doing this but it failing to unzip where i am wrong.

Comment: Search the net for "zlib" to find documentation of libz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly answering your question, but you could use [ZipKit](http://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/Home). It is an Obj-C framework for using zip files.