# High level process of extracting images from a container

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, compression, logic

Right, this is the problem I have a container (rar,zip) which contains images png's tiffs bmps or jpegs in an order.

The file extension **isnt** zip or rar though but uses the same compression.

I want to pull out a list of images contained within the file in the numerical order, then depending on the user decision go to the image selected.

I'm not after any code just the high level thought process/logic of how this can be achieved and how it could be achieved on iphone OS.

From what i know of iphone OS it uses a kind of sandbox environment so how would this effect the process as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the `libz` framework in your project and write some C to manage zipped data. Or you can use Objective-C wrapper classes [others have written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230351/is-there-any-zip-decompression-for-iphone).

Your application resides in its own sandbox. You can include zip files in the "bundle", i.e. add them to your project, and copy them to the application's [Documents folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272544/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-documents-directory-on-an-iphone) to work with them. Or you can copy archived data over the network to the application's Documents folder if you don't want to include files in your project.

I don't think the extension matters so much as the data being in the format you expect it to be.

Everything I wrote above is for zip-ped files. If you're working with rar-formatted archives, you'll need to look at making a static library for the iPhone, perhaps from the [UnRAR source code](ftp://sunsite.unc.edu/pub/Linux/utils/compress/).