# How can I read the iTunesMetadata.plist in Objective-C? (ipa file is on disk)

Tags: objective-c, plist, bundle

Ok I can get the list of IPA files in my iTunes folder. what I want to do is be able to read the plist file in the IPA file.

I'm very new to Objective-C so sorry if this is an obvious question (I did look).

I tried the following but it comes back null.

```
// i = NSURL. value eg. "file://localhost/Users/jiyeon/Desktop/test/test.ipa"
NSDictionary *plistInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[i absoluteString] 
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iTunesMetadata.plist"]];
```

However plistInfo just ends up being null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try -(NSString *)path [NSURL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSDictionary *plistInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[i path] 
                       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iTunesMetadata.plist"]];
```

this should work

Comment: Nope that doesn't work either. :/ I think I am mega-newbie on this. The IPA file appears to be a zip (and plist file is in that). I tried NSBundle on it as well but that doesn't work. Is there a command for reading zips? If extract then I can just access directly.

Comment: You need to extract the file first. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230351/is-there-any-zip-decompression-for-iphone