# How read iTunesMetadata.plist in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist

Searching for anti-piracy systems many people answer to check the content of the file iTunesMetadata.plist. This file should be present if it was purchased on iTunes. I'm able to locate it but cannot open it. It seems in binary format.
Trying to open it with Windows doesn't work (unzip too nothing) but on my Mac it works (Apple binary property list). Seems in a binary format. My questions:

1. How can I open it in xCode and read the content (using Xcode 4.2)?
2. It's allowed to read the content or would this operation not pass the validation process by Apple?

I know, there are many checks we could implement but it's only a better of time they would be by-passed. BTW it's at least a good xCode exercise for me :)

Thank's a lot for your help!

Simon

Comment: I've found on MAC I could use `putil` to convert the file, but on xCode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793347/how-can-i-read-the-itunesmetadata-plist-in-objective-c-ipa-file-is-on-disk

Comment: Still read before asking. This doesn't help. It says I would need to extract the plist before, but it's not an archive format but binary property. BTW I've found myself answer on point 1 using `NSPropertyListSerialization`. I've only the question two open. Can I proceed with these checks or could I have problems during Apple's approval procedure? Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

plist type files can be read on Windows using 'plist_editor' software.